# creating nested nodes using Groovy xml Building

Tags: java, groovy

I have the below xml, **Updated added "symptoms"**

```
<EBF>
<EBFINFO>
    <EBFNUM>EBF262323</EBFNUM>  
    <RELEASEDATETIME>May 06, 2011</RELEASEDATETIME>
    <SYMPTOMS>
    <br> INFA252994 - 910 : While running concurrent session Workflow manager hangs and workflow monitor does not respond</br>
    <br> INFA262323 - 910 : pmcmd, pmdtm and all LM clients on Windows fail to connect to IS when IPv6 is installed but all IPv6 interfaces are disabled</br>
    </SYMPTOMS>
    <FILES>
       <FILE>
        <PATH>H:\EBF262323\EBF262323_Client_Installer_win32_x86\EBFs\clients\PmClient\client\bin\ACE.dll_bak</PATH>
        <CHECKSUM>303966974</CHECKSUM>
        <AFFECTEDFILES>
            <CHECKSUM>3461283269</CHECKSUM>
            <PATH>C:\clients\PmClient\CommandLineUtilities\PC\server\bin\ACE.dll</PATH>
            <PATH>C:\clients\PmClient\client\bin\ACE.dll</PATH>
        </AFFECTEDFILES>
       </FILE>
    </FILES>
    <NOTES>
    </NOTES>
</EBFINFO>
</EBF>
```

Note: In the above xml ebf\enfinfo\files\file\affectedfiles\path and ebf\enfinfo\files\file can be one or more

which I am parsing and generating another xml out of it

```
    def records = new XmlParser().parseText(rs)
    csm.ebfHistory(){
    records.EBFINFO.each{
    ebfHistory_info(num:it.EBFNUM.text(),
        release_date_time:it.RELEASEDATETIME.text()
        ){

            it.FILES.FILE.each{ //says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'FILES' on null object
                ebfHistory_fileinfo(file_path:it.PATH.text(),
                    file_checksum:it.CHECKSUM.text()
                ){
                    ebfHistory_fileinfo_affectedfiles(
                        afile_checksum:it.CHECKSUM.text(),
                        afile_path:it.PATH.text()
                        )
                }
            }
        }
  }             
}
```

something like below

```
<ebfHistory>
    <ebfHistory_info num="EBF262323",release_date_time="May 06, 2011">
        <ebfHistory_fileinfo file_checksum="303966974">
            <ebfHistory_fileinfo_affectedfiles afile_checksum="3461283269">
                <path>C:\clients\PmClient\CommandLineUtilities\PC\server\bin\ACE.dll</path>
                <path>C:\clients\PmClient\client\bin\ACE.dll</path>
            </ebfHistory_fileinfo_affectedfiles>
        </ebfHistory_fileinfo>
    </ebfHistory_info>
</ebfHistory>
```

but instead I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'FILES' on null object` where am i going wrong? Please help somebody. Thanks

**Updated code (working)**

```
def records = new XmlParser().parseText(rs)
        csm.ebfHistory(){   
            records.EBFINFO.each{   ebfinfo ->
                ebfHistory_info(num:ebfinfo.EBFNUM.text(),
                    release_date_time:ebfinfo.RELEASEDATETIME.text())
                    {
                        ebfinfo.SYMPTOMS.br.each{
                            ebfHistory_symptom(name:it.text())
                        }
                    }
            }   
            ebfHistory_dump(rs){
                "${rs}"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `it` no longer refers to each `EBFINFO`, because you are in another closure--the `ebfHistory_info` closure.

Instead, explicitly name the `EBFINFO` object:

```
records.EBFINFO.each { ebfinfo -> // <-- Give it a name
    ebfHistory_info(num:it.EBFNUM.text(),
                    release_date_time:it.RELEASEDATETIME.text()) {
        ebfinfo.FILES.FILE.each { // <-- Use the name here
```

Same thing in the `ebfHistory_fileinfo_affectedfiles` parameters.

Comment: EBFINFO can be one or more so still can it be uniquely identified?

Comment: The `it` variable is an [implicit variable](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures#Closures-Implicitvariables) that is the parameter of a single-argument closure. As I said, you're *creating another closure* when you call `ebfHistory_info`, thus `it` is re-bound in the new closure's scope. You must *explicitly name* the EBFINFO instance instead of using the implicit `it`, because `it` is no longer the EBFINFO once you're in the new closure.

Comment: Please look at my updated question, i tried you way but getting some error

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Oh, I'm stuck in Ruby mode today--the Groovy syntax is different; updated answer.

Comment: one small correction, `it` has to be replaced by `ebfinfo` in its closure. I updated my question with working code. Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Yes, that's what the above code does. Glad you got it working!